# How to combine several similar .csv files into one dataframe with given structure

Tags: python, r, csv, dataframe

I have many .csv files which are similar in structure:

```
1.csv

Type n
A   1
B   20
C   34
D   5
...

2.csv

Type n
A   2
B   15
C   16
D   5
...
```

I want to combine them in something like:

```
Type  n1   n2
  A   1    2
  B   20   15
  C   34   16
  D   5    5
  ...
```

When I use lapply I get

```
 Type n  Type   n
  A   1    A    2
  B   20   B    15
  C   34   C    16
  D   5    D    5
  ...
```

Is there any simple way to combine them properly?

I'm open for solutions in either R or Python

Comment: Are they *similar* in structure, or are they *identical* in structure. If *similar*, `merge` or `match` might be needed. If *identical*, a simple `cbind` should do the trick (in R). Drop the first column from all but the first file when `cbind`ing, and use `make.names` or `paste` to get unique names for the "n" columns.

Comment: Presumably you want something like `merge`, possibly in combination with `do.call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Interpretation 1: Identical data structure for each CSV

Here are two options to consider if the structure is *identical*, but first some sample data:

```
cat("Type n", "A  1", "B  20", "C  34", "D  5", sep = "\n", file = "myfile1.txt")
cat("Type n", "A  2", "B  15", "C  16", "D  5", sep = "\n", file = "myfile2.txt")
```

Option 1: Drop the first column when you're reading the data in by using `"NULL"` (with quotes) as the `colClasses` for the column that needs to be dropped. Use `cbind` to put the files together.

```
x <- read.table("myfile1.txt", header=TRUE)
y <- read.table("myfile2.txt", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("NULL", "numeric"))
cbind(x, y)
#   Type  n  n
# 1    A  1  2
# 2    B 20 15
# 3    C 34 16
# 4    D  5  5

## For more files:
## do.call(cbind, list(x, y, ...))
```

Option 2: Read the files in normally, then subset with a `c(FALSE, TRUE)` vector, put everything in a `list` and `cbind` together with the first column from any of the objects.

```
x1 <- read.table("myfile1.txt", header = TRUE)
y1 <- read.table("myfile2.txt", header = TRUE)

fileList <- list(x1, y1)
cbind(x1[1], do.call(cbind, fileList)[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
#   Type  n n.1
# 1    A  1   2
# 2    B 20  15
# 3    C 34  16
# 4    D  5   5
```

Of course, the above are just minimal examples. I'm presuming that you actually have more than 2 columns in each file. Use a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s that actually match your columns to keep and drop (respectively) for the second option, and `"NULL"` and object classes for the first option.

---

#### Interpretation 2: Similar data structure for each CSV

If the data structure are *similar* but not *identical*, you might need to use `merge` instead. Consider the following sample data. The first three files have the same structure, but the fourth one, `"myfile4.txt"` has A, B, D, and E as the "Type" values, while the other three have "A", "B", "C", and "D"

```
cat("Type n", "A  1", "B  20", "C  34", "D  5", sep = "\n", file = "myfile1.txt")
cat("Type n", "A  2", "B  15", "C  16", "D  5", sep = "\n", file = "myfile2.txt")
cat("Type n", "A  1", "B   5", "C   6", "D  7", sep = "\n", file = "myfile3.txt")
cat("Type n", "A  8", "B   9", "D  11", "E  0", sep = "\n", file = "myfile4.txt")
```

Here's how we can tackle this.

1. Bulk read in the files:

   ```
   x <- list.files(pattern="myfile")
   y <- lapply(x, read.table, header = TRUE)
   ```
2. Multiple `merge`s will probably result in an error if it can't make unique names. Help `merge` out by making unique names for the non-id columns to start.

   ```
   library(data.table) ## for `setnames`
   ## setnames will silently assign new names 
   ##   to the original data in list "y"
   invisible(lapply(seq_along(y), function(z) 
     setnames(y[[z]], "n", paste("n", z, sep = "_"))))
   ```
3. Use `Reduce` to `merge` the list items together using the "Type" column as the "id".

   ```
   Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Type", all = TRUE), y)
   #   Type n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4
   # 1    A   1   2   1   8
   # 2    B  20  15   5   9
   # 3    C  34  16   6  NA
   # 4    D   5   5   7  11
   # 5    E  NA  NA  NA   0
   ```

Comment: `merge` doesn't even get a mention?  Poor `merge`.  It's not it's fault it's not as efficient as cbind.  It does a great job at what it does.

Comment: And I just saw your comment above.  Might be worth incorporating into your answer for future searches?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, merge incorporated.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of downvoting for little/no reason in the R/SO world.

Answer (score 1):

in Python you should use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) to perform these operations:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep='\s+', index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', sep='\s+', index_col=0)

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[16]: 
       n   n
Type        
A      1   2
B     20  15
C     34  16
D      5   5
```

If you expect more automated columns renaming:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['1', '2'])
Out[20]: 
      n1  n2
Type        
A      1   2
B     20  15
C     34  16
D      5   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here assuming no merging needs to be done. If you have three files for example, you can read them in like this:

```
n <- 1:3
x <- lapply(sprintf('%s.csv', n), read.csv)
```

You just want to drop the first column in every table, so you can use `sapply()` on `[[.data.frame` to remove the unwanted column, and then combine it all into one data frame.

```
data.frame(Type = x[[1]]$Type, sapply(x, '[[', -1))
```

Or if you really want the names in the form `n1`, `n2` etc.:

```
data.frame(
  Type = x[[1]]$Type, 
  setNames(lapply(x, '[[', -1), paste0('n', n))
)
```